# Text-ellipsis in the beginning with "right-to-left" languages like Arabic in Angular

Tags: angular, right-to-left, left-to-right

I have a configuration to display a long text, cut with ellipsis in the beginning.
For instance,we have a long text like
`MainInterface.SubGroup.InitialSystemActuator`
and the displayed value will be the following :
`...roup.InitialSystemActuator`

What I do is first reverse the string as following:

```
const reversedStr = this.str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Then I have the following reversed string:
`rotautcAmetsySlaitinI.puorGbuS.ecafretnIniaM`

Then I apply the following css styles :

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

.ellipsis-backward {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="ellipsis-backward">rotautcAmetsySlaitinI.puorGbuS.ecafretnIniaM</span>
</div>
```

In this way, I will have the correct text with the ellipsis in the beginning of the long text.

Anyway, this was only a workaround and there are several problems with this strategy. The main issue is to have the ellipsis on the right (the beginning) for Arabic-like languages since it flows right-to-left.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Please clarify the desired end result...

Comment: I want to have the ellipsis always on the correct position regardless from the language. If it is Latin language, should be on the left. If it is Arabic, should be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `:dir(...)` selector can solve your problem...

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

.ellipsis-backward {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.ellipsis-backward:dir(rtl) {
  direction: ltr;
}

/* demo only */
.ellipsis-backward[dir="rtl"] {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="ellipsis-backward">rotautcAmetsySlaitinI.puorGbuS.ecafretnIniaM</span>
  <span dir="rtl" class="ellipsis-backward">rotautcAmetsySlaitinI.puorGbuS.ecafretnIniaM</span>
</div>
```